# Global Raster of geographic distances

Tags: r, distance, raster, shapefile, rasterize

Im wondering if someone has built a raster of the continents of the world where each cell equals the distance of that cell cell to the nearest shore. This map would highlight the land areas that are most isolated inland.

I would imagine this would simply `rasterize` a shapefile of the global boundaries and then calculate the distances.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `raster::distance`, which calculates the distance from each `NA` cell to the closest non-`NA` cell. You just need to create a raster that has `NA` for land pixels, and some other value for non-land pixels.

[image]

Here's how:

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

# Create a raster template for rasterizing the polys. 
# (set the desired grid resolution with res)
r <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, res=1)

# Rasterize and set land pixels to NA
r2 <- rasterize(wrld_simpl, r, 1)
r3 <- mask(is.na(r2), r2, maskvalue=1, updatevalue=NA)

# Calculate distance to nearest non-NA pixel
d <- distance(r3)

# Optionally set non-land pixels to NA (otherwise values are "distance to non-land")
d <- d*r2
```

To create the plot above (I like `rasterVis` for plotting, but you could use `plot(r)`):

```
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(d/1000, margin=FALSE, at=seq(0, maxValue(d)/1000, length=100),
          colorkey=list(height=0.6), main='Distance to coast')
```

Comment: Great answer! Two followup questions: 1) can the resolution of the pixels be further downscaled? 2) The values of the map are interpreted as kilometers?

Comment: @IDelToro (1) you can set the desired resolution where we define `r` (the `res` argument, here in degrees); (2) take a look at `?raster` - if the data are "unprojected" (i.e., geographic), as it is here, then the output of `distance` is in metres. Otherwise, it's in the units of the projection. Note that when I plot it, I divide by 1000, giving km.

Comment: Thanks! Would you create a raster of latitude (or longitude) values the same way?

Comment: @IDelToro: you can derive these from one of your other rasters, e.g. `lon <- lat <- d; lon[] <- coordinates(d)[, 1]; lat[] <- coordinates(d)[, 2]`. If making from scratch, start with matrix `m` of, e.g., longitudes, and then `raster(m)`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Of general interest: I found that increasing res to 0.5 resulted in a notable increase of processing time (which is fine) but increasing further to 0.1 degree never completes. Anyone else find this? There's no error, it just consumes 100% of 1 core and gives no hint as to whether it's running or has hung.