# How to subset a raster based on grid cell values

Tags: r, cell, raster

My following question builds on the solution proposed by @jbaums on this post: [Global Raster of geographic distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555709/global-raster-of-geographic-distances/45407328#45407328)

For the purpose of reproducing the example, I have a raster dataset of distances to the nearest coastline:

```
library(rasterVis); library(raster); library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

# Create a raster template for rasterizing the polys. 
r <- raster(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, res=1)
# Rasterize and set land pixels to NA
r2 <- rasterize(wrld_simpl, r, 1)
r3 <- mask(is.na(r2), r2, maskvalue=1, updatevalue=NA) 
# Calculate distance to nearest non-NA pixel
d <- distance(r3) # if claculating distances on land instead of ocean: d <- distance(r3)
# Optionally set non-land pixels to NA (otherwise values are "distance to non-land")
d <- d*r2 
levelplot(d/1000, margin=FALSE, at=seq(0, maxValue(d)/1000, length=100),colorkey=list(height=0.6), main='Distance to coast (km)')
```

The data looks like this:
[image: output plot]

From here, I need to subset the distance raster (d), or create a new raster, that only contains cells for which the distance to coastline is less than 200 km. I have tried using getValues() to identify the cells for which the value <= 200 (as show below), but so far without success. Can anyone help? Am I on the right track?

```
#vector of desired cell numbers
my.pts <- which(getValues(d) <= 200)
# create raster the same size as d filled with NAs
bar <- raster(ncols=ncol(d), nrows=nrow(d), res=res(d))
bar[] <- NA
# replace the values with those in d
bar[my.pts] <- d[my.pts]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, you can treat a raster like a matrix here right after you `d <- d*r2` line:

```
d[d>=200000]<-NA
levelplot(d/1000, margin=FALSE, at=seq(0, maxValue(d)/1000, length=100),colorkey=list(height=0.6), main='Distance to coast (km)')
```

(in case you forgot: the unit is in meters so the threshold should be 200000, not 200)